# What would be the most efficient way to store multiple sets of fixed arrays (std::vector)?

Tags: c++, data-structures, time, processing-efficiency, space-efficiency

As it stands, I have a game I writing, utilizing PCG (Procedural Content Generation). I was wondering if there was a better way to store the vertices of my polygon with certain library restrictions (Box2D is my chosen physics engine). Currently, I have this:

```
std::vector<b2Vec2> topChain;
std::vector<b2Vec2> bottomChain;
std::vector<b2Vec2> eastCap;
std::vector<b2Vec2> westCap;
```

Box2D has a limitation ( as far as I'm aware ) that polygon fixtures can contain at most 8 vertices. Given I have sloping terrain, 8 vertices isn't enough for the smooth terrain I'm looking for. The solution was to slice each sloping section into a quad.

However, my concern here is efficiency, and one thing I noticed is the time and memory it requires to fill these vectors.

Hovering over each class name in Visual Studio, shows that `b2Vec2` is a whopping 8 bytes per.
The container class of `std::vector` takes another 32 bytes.

What would be the most efficient data structure for this problem?

Comment: Are you using a release build? How are you populating the vector? You can't get much smaller than 8 bytes per 2d coordinate in c++ unless you use half floats

Comment: I'm in release, and as for populating vectors. I need to scan an image to get coordinates within the sprite image to overlay physical shapes.

Comment: Could you post this bit about half floats as an answer? I'm not familiar with this concept.

Comment: If the container is fixed size, then `std::array` may be a better option.